# How to make my application auto switch language depending on computer langage settings?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

**I want to create an .EXE in english and french.
When PC config is french, exe is in french. When PC config is english, exe is in english.**

I have used the Delphi XE Language localization wizard. My application is French; I have added English/US.

I have translated my strings into English.

When I set application default as English, it works fine; the application is in English. When I set default as French, it is French.

Now I change my computer settings and put it as English/US - however my application stays in French...

How to make it auto-switch depending on my PC configuration?

I have french as default langage in Resources and I have translated my application to English.
 I compile the .exe: I have project1.exe and Project1.ENG.

I close delphi: I lunch project1.exe : it is french. I close the .exe switch my PC to english. I lunch project1.exe and it is still in french !

**How do I switch it to english ?**

I have also read that:

The method how VCL chooses the initial resource DLL is:
First VCL looks from system registry under HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Borland\Locales a string entry whose name matches the full path name of the application or library. If VCL finds such an entry it load a resource DLL matching data of the entry.

PS. I have tried with firemobkey Tlang, and it switches it automatically when I change my PC langage configuration.

Comment: It sounds like you already have everything figured out except for how to check the computer's localization settings. That's the question you should be asking, which can be found in numerous resources on the net.

Comment: isn't it automatic ? I mean: Delphi does not load the resource automatically according to the PC langage configuration ?

Comment: Not that I know of. If it did, I'm sure the docs should say something about it.

Comment: Delphi's localization framework detects the current language at startup and loads the appropriate localized resources based on what you have provided.  However, if you change the language while the app is still running, it does not update automatically.  You have to detect the change yourself and reload your resources as needed.  There are many third party localization components/libraries for Delphi to help make this easier.

Comment: You can detect a change in system language by catching the [`WM_SETTINGCHANGE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms725497.aspx) message. If its `lParam` is non-zero, it is a pointer to a null-terminated string, check it for `'intl'`.

Comment: I am talking about executing the .EXE generated file: The EXE files does not care about my PC configuration and runs ALWAYS as French (even if my PC is english/us)

Comment: Remy is talking about executing the .EXE as well. He's described the way the application detects *the current language at startup* (when the application is launched).

Comment: Ok, but how do I switch then from french to english ? Is there a snippet somewhere availble ?
(The TLang firemonkey is not available on VCL. Any idea why ? 
This one swithces it automatically)

Comment: It is still very unclear: I have french as default langage in Resources and I have translated my application to English. I compile the .exe: I have project1.exe and Project1.ENG. 

I close delphi: I lunch project1.exe : it is french. I close the .exe switch my PC to english. I lunch project1.exe and it is still in french !
How do I switch it to english ?

Comment: I read that : 
The method how VCL chooses the initial resource DLL is:
First VCL looks from system registry under HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Borland\Locales a string entry whose name matches the full path name of the application or library. If VCL finds such an entry it load a resource DLL matching data of the entry.

Comment: I'm still unclear on what you are doing.

Comment: I want to create an .EXE in english and french.When PC config is french, exe is in french. When PC config is english, exe is in english. cannot be simpler.

Comment: I have opened a new quetsion with screenshots so you undertsand better: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31903056/how-to-internationalize-my-application-in-delphi-xe

Comment: Seeing your new question, this explains why it was not working for you. You were changing the wrong settings. You appear to have been changing the regional format settings, rather than the language display settings. If you've never installed a language pack, then your computer doesn't even have the ability to change between languages.