# how to internationalize my application in Delphi XE?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe8

I am using the Translation Manager Included in Delphi (xe8, but should be the same in older version)

I go to Projet->langages->add (choose english).

Then I translate the texts(here the button)

[image]

I update it all and compile it all:
I got the .exe and .enu file and it is french.

[image]

When I go to Projet->languages->set Active and I choose english, I compile it all and my application is now in english (button says **hello**)

That's great.
[image]

However my goal is that my application AUTOMATICALLY swicthes from french->english when computer config changes
ex : I change my PC settings to english:

[image]

(I do the same with keyboard setting)

However my applicatin ALWAYS stays withe the default langage I put in Project->Langages->Set Active

**How to make my Project.exe automatically choose the right langage depending on my PC configuration ?**

Comment: You didn't switch the language but format settings.

Comment: You've named three separate versions here. XE, XE2 and XE3. Which is it?

Comment: it is XE8.. But I guess : it does not matter if this is XE2-8

Comment: about format: this is a clue ! I also modified the keyboard: what should I modify on my PC to be sure it works ?

Comment: In [this article](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/install-or-change-a-display-language) you can read how to install/switch display language (make sure you have sufficient SKU; for what I can say, this feature is not available in Home editions).

Comment: Do you mean: that what I did is correct ? 
 And when an English Windows user will run my project.exe, he will get automatically the english version of project.exe ? Is there any way to test it in my french windows 7 version ?

Comment: If it is XE8 say so. As it stands the question is misleading. Please fix it.

Comment: Your question still says XE. You are changing regionalisation settings. Change the language.

Comment: Ok David, change the langage : but HOW/WHERE ?

Comment: As mentioned, you need to install the language pack, assuming you have a version of Windows which is capable of it. If you're running Home edition, this feature is not available. Typically, open Windows Update and look at your optional updates. There should be a number of different language packs available there. A simple Google search would tell you this.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://dxgettext.po.dk/ replacement for standart `Translation Manager`.

This adds the support of well-known [gettext](/questions/tagged/gettext) toolset to your project.